# InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

There are many questions around this topic I know but I tried different things and couldn't solve. So my list return code is this, this is QuestionsController, model is Question

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     return View(await _context.Question.ToListAsync());
}
```

This is my cshtml and model tag

```
@model IEnumerable<SocialLearningCommunity.Models.Question>
```

Error

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
> ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SocialLearningCommunity.Models.Question]',
> but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
> 'SocialLearningCommunity.Models.User'.

Data class

```
public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
public DbSet<Question> Question { get; set; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to post the full index view too if you need some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your index view has this line of code

```
@model SocialLearningCommunity.Models.User
```

but you are trying to send to the view from the controller action

```
List <SocialLearningCommunity.Models.Question>
```

you have to decide which of models you have to use. Or you can have question model in Question view, not in Index one. Or you have a partial view with User model.

Comment: I solved it, the problem was I had @model in Layout.cshtml which is shared so I have changed that.